# Is it possible to Integrate wso2 MB with wso2 BPS?

Tags: wso2, integration, wso2-business-process, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I'm currently working with WSO2 Message Broker and I need to connect this product to WSO2 BPS without using ESB. So my question is , is it possible to do so? or I have to use WSO2 ESB to integrate MB with BPS?

Comment: It depends on your use case. It not a not a must to use ESB. Read on http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/01/configuring-jms-transport-in-wso2-business-process-server-bps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi any JMS client or an AMQP client can directly talk to the WSO2 BPS, also the Business Process Server is packaged with WSO2 Message Broker  , which implements Advanced Message Queuing Protocol Therefore, the scenario should be possible.

This article describes how to enable JMS transport in WSO2 BPS and how to configure it to communicate with JMS providers such as: Active MQ, Apache Qpid.

You may refer ,   http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/01/configuring-jms-transport-in-wso2-business-process-server-bps/